# Golang: extract time from datetime string

Tags: go

I am trying to extract the time from a datetime string in golang, here is what I have:

```
func GetTimeStr(d string) string {
    layout := "2014-09-12T11:45:26"
    d = d[:len(layout)]
    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, d)
    return t.Format("15:04:05")
}
```

My input look like this:

```
2022-09-23T16:28:19.846821Z
```

However I am getting `00:00:00`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't ignore errors! The layout has to be a specific time instant, not an arbitrary time. Use layout `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z`.

Comment: Yes, error handling in golang is essential. If you can not parse the timestamp to your layout, it is wise to check the error for being not nil `t, err := time.Parse(layout,d)` followed by `if err != nil {return ""}` to avoid a panic in your program and handle an empty return of your `GetTimeStr(d)` on a higher layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout string is wrong. Try changing it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(GetTimeStr("2022-09-23T16:28:19.846821Z"))
}
func GetTimeStr(d string) string {
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05"
    d = d[:len(layout)]
    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, d)
    return t.Format("15:04:05")
}
```

Comment: Great answer Cetin. In my case my layout needed to look like layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05" without the T